# Where are the Website Payments Pro credentials?

Tags: java, paypal, payflowpro

I am writing a java program to process direct payments using paypal. Naturally I am using the payflow API and the file [`paypalflow.java`](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_download_sdks#PayflowPro). The file requires the credentials below. I create a sandbox account, and within that a Website Payments Pro preconfigured Test account. Where do I find the credentials for the variables below?

```
gv_BNCode       = " ";
gv_APIUser      = " ";
//Fill in the gv_APIPassword variable yourself, the wizard will not do this automatically
gv_APIPassword  = " ";
gv_APIVendor    = " ";
gv_APIPartner   = " ";
gv_Env          = "pilot";
unique_id       = "";
```

Comment: I have done so whenever the answers solve my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**To retrieve PayPal Sandbox API credentials:**
To retrieve regular PayPal API credentials, used with the PayPal API's such as DoDirectPayment, you would go to https://developer.paypal.com/ > Applications > Sandbox Accounts > Pick the dropdown for your account > API Access.

If you didn't create a preconfigured account, but rather a 'manual' account, you would need to log in to the account on https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/ and navigate to 'Profile' > 'My selling tools' > 'API Access' > Update > 'Request API Credentials' > 'PayPal API credentials' > 'API Signature'.

(Or 'Profile' > 'Request API Credentials' > 'PayPal API credentials' > 'API Signature', depending on your account type).

This will get you an API username, API password and API signature.

Note: PayPal Sandbox API calls that make use of an API username, API password and API signature for authentication, using NVP for communication, should be sent to https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp

Other endpoints are listed on https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_endpoints

---

**Payflow Pro:**
You, however, are trying to use PayPal Payflow Pro, which is a different product and a different set of API's, with a different set of credentials.
PayPal Payflow Pro can't be tested through the Developer Central at https://developer.paypal.com/ or the PayPal Sandbox at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/
Instead, you will need to sign up for a regular Payflow account at https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_payflow-get-started-outside
Proceed to fill in all details, including the "login details". Once you get to the billing section, simply cancel out of the registration process by closing the tab.
You will have a Payflow Pro account in a 'test' state at this point.

The 'partner' will be: PayPal
The 'vendor' will be: The merchant login you created during the registration process
The 'password' will be: The merchant password you created during the registration process
The 'user' will be: empty

Alternatively, if you want to create a dedicated user to use for the API's, you can log on to https://manager.paypal.com with the credentials and go to 'User settings' (or something of similar wording), and create a secondary user. The username for this user would need to be filled in in 'user', as well as the password of the user.

It may take up to an hour before new credentials become active.

Note: Payflow Pro test API calls should be sent to https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com/
Live Payflow Pro API calls should be sent to https://payflowpro.paypal.com/

Comment: Thanks. I will try you suggestion and let you know how it went.

Comment: When it asks you to choose a processor, choose any (or your preferred) processor. PayPal Payflow Pro doesn't actually connect to any processors when in 'Test' (or 'Pilot') mode.

Comment: I use the following values, star(*) means my values obtained from creating account. But I end up with the error "User authentication failed". I get the error whether gv_APIUser is empty or not. :::

gv_BNCode  = "PF-CCWizard";
gv_APIUser  = "*My Unique Vendor ID*";
    gv_APIPassword = "*my password*";
    gv_APIVendor = "*My Unique Vendor ID*";
    gv_APIPartner = "PayPal";
 gv_Env   = "pilot";
 unique_id  = "";

Comment: gv_APIUser should be empty unless you specifically created a user.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me in the right direction. But for some reason, when I try making a "DirectPayment," I am still getting "User authentication failed" from paypal in the "RESPMSG."